# Redefinition of ..., previously declared here

Tags: c++, class

I know there are plenty of questions like these, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for me. Anyways, I have 4 files, two header files and two cpp files, one implementation and one main.

**Header File 1**

```
#ifndef SORTEDINTERFACE_H
#define SORTEDINTERFACE_H
using namespace std;

template<class ListItemType>
class sortedInterface
{
public:
    virtual int sortedGetLength() const = 0;
    virtual bool sortedIsEmpty() const = 0;
    virtual bool sortedInsert(const ListItemType& newItem) = 0;
    virtual bool sortedRemove(const ListItemType& anItem) = 0;
    virtual bool sortedRetrieve(const ListItemType& anItem) = 0;
    virtual int getItemCount () = 0;

private:
    virtual int locatePosition(const ListItemType& anItem) = 0;
};
#endif // SORTEDINTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

**Header File 2**

```
#ifndef SORTED_H
#define SORTED_H
#include "sortedInterface.h"
using namespace std;

template<class ListItemType>
class sorted : public sortedInterface<ListItemType>
{
public:
    sorted();
    int sortedGetLength() const;
    bool sortedIsEmpty() const;
    bool sortedInsert(const ListItemType& newItem);
    bool sortedRemove(const ListItemType& anItem);
    bool sortedRetrieve(const ListItemType& anItem);
    int getItemCount();

private:
    static const int DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE = 10;
    ListItemType items[DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE];
    int itemCount;
    int maxItems;
    int locatePosition(const ListItemType& anItem);
};
#include "sorted.cpp"
#endif // SORTED_H
```

**CPP File**

```
#include "sorted.h"
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

template<class ListItemType>
sorted<ListItemType>::sorted() : itemCount(0), maxItems(DEFAULT_LIST_SIZE)
{
}  // end default constructor
```

**Main CPP File**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "sorted.h"
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sorted<string> test;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile I get the errors/warnings
1. redefinition of 'sorted::sorted() 
2. sorted::sorted()' previously declared here

When I comment out the #include "sorted.cpp" at the end of header file #2, it works, but then in my main file, it doesn't regonize my sorted test object.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the command line you are using to compile?

Comment: Remove `#include "sorted.cpp"` from header file 2.

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks to code in. Also if i remove #include "sorted.cpp", then I get countless errors for trying to create my sorted object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you compiling sorted.cpp also . i think you should not .

Comment: It is an answer to the question; the problem is that every file that includes `"sorted.h"` also gets a copy of the implementation included, so only one file in any program can include `"sorted.h"` and the fact that the OP is getting the problem almost certainly stems from trying to link more than one object file that includes `"sorted.h"`, and there are two such files in the question — `main.cpp` and `sorted.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the sorted.cpp file at the end, then you must realize that sorted.cpp is not a separate module -- it is just the implementation of your template class implementation.  Therefore you should remove the first three lines from that .cpp file.

```
#include "sorted.h"
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;
```

Those lines above should not be in the template implementation file.

Also, I would rename sorted.cpp to sorted.ipp or some other extension to something indicating it is just a template implementation file and not a separate source module to be compiled.